# Placing text in the center of svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am creating an `<svg>`, and I want to put text in the center of the `<svg>`,  when I click on the first button, the svg doesn't have text, when I click on the second button, the text show up. The first one I just add the position of svg.  but I don't know why the text does not show up?

Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testbtm').click(function() {
    var str = '<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content" style="position:absolute; left:200; top:300;"\
            <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
            <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>'
    var svgElement = $(str);
    svgElement.children('text').text(1);
    svgElement.attr("class", "hexagon ui-widget-content");
    $("#display").append(svgElement);
  }); //end click 
  $('#testbtm2').click(function() {
    $('.hexagon').each(function() {
      var svgElement = $('<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content">\
            <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
            <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>');
      svgElement.children('text').text(1);
      svgElement.attr("class", "hexagon ui-widget-content");
      $("#display").append(svgElement);
    });
  }); // end click
}); // end ready
```

```css
#display {
  height: 500 px;
  width: 500 px;
  border: 1 px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
<button id="testbtm">test</button>
<button id="testbtm2">test2</button>
```

Comment: When I click the first button, a hexagon appears; when I click the second button, the number 1 appears in the middle of the hexagon. Is that not the expected result? (using IE)

Comment: no, I want the first hexagon have number too. I am confuse why the second hexagon has number, but the first dose not. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket `>` on your opening `svg` tag.

Comment: Hi, but when I create the hexagon, I already put the text in it, why the hexagon and the text do not come in the same time? The second button I create the hexagon and the text and hexagon appear at the same time. But the first button only has the hexagon. Thank you

Comment: @tiger The missing `>` messes up the text tag after it.